# Bootstrap 4 Navigation Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to implement a navigation sidebar in Bootstrap 4 which is toggled on or off, as demonstrated here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/Tp24nX8DNz

Everything works fine however I can't seem to figure out why there is an initial delay when the toggle button is clicked to display the sidebar. The delay isn't there when clicking the toggle again to hide the sidebar.

I've tried setting transition-delay to 0 in the sidebar but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: IT seems to be defined `const TRANSITION_DURATION = 600` in the source of bootstrap.js.

Comment: I don't think that is causing it as the delay happens at the start before the transition, not during the transition